# Im having a run time Error type mismatch when i try to run sql

Tags: excel, vba

here is my code

```
Option Explicit
Dim niFlag As Integer

Private Sub OpenDB(ByRef cnn As ADODB.Connection)

cnn.ConnectionString = "Driver={Microsoft Excel Driver (*.xls, *.xlsx, *.xlsm, 
*.xlsb)};DBQ=" & _


ActiveWorkbook.Path & Application.PathSeparator & ActiveWorkbook.name

cnn.Open

End Sub


Private Sub cmdPopul_Click()

Dim strSQL As String

Dim cnn As ADODB.Connection

Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset

niFlag = 1

strSQL = "Select Distinct [Group] From [Data$] Order by [Group]"

Set cnn = New ADODB.Connection

OpenDB cnn

cmbCompany.Clear

Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset

rs.Open strSQL, cnn, adOpenKeySet, adLockOptimistic

Set cnn = Nothing

If rs.RecordCount > 0 Then

Do While Not rs.EOF


**cmbCompany.AddItem rs.Fields(0)** 'the error is here


rs.MoveNext

Loop

Else

MsgBox "I was not able to find any unique Group.", vbCritical + vbOKOnly

Set rs = Nothing

Exit Sub

End If

End Sub
```

Thanks for helping

Comment: What is `cmbCompany`? Where have you declared it?

Comment: What is the value of `rs.Fields(0)` when it crashes?  Is it `Null` or some other non-numeric, non-string value?

Comment: @Pankaj Jaju cmbCompany is a combobox to be filled by the specific values of "Group" columns in Data Sheet

Comment: @YowE3k, i didnt declare the values null but the data being stored is purely string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your code to this:

```
If rs.RecordCount > 0 Then

    Do While Not rs.EOF

        Debug.Print rs.Fields(1)
        Stop
        Debug.Print rs.Fields(0)
        Stop
        '**cmbCompany.AddItem rs.Fields(0)**    'the error is here
        rs.MoveNext
    Loop
Else
```

See what you get in the immediate window, when the code stops. Then amend it further. If you are having a `Null` value then try the following:

```
If not IsNull (rs.Fields(0)) then
```

Comment: thanks for the reply, after inserting your code the program breaks in rs.Fields(1) and then pops up an error saying "Item Cannot be found in the collection corresponding to the requested name or ordinal"

Comment: then i tried to remove the debug.print rs.fields(1) and nothing happens

Comment: yeah and also in the immediate window 2 Nulls were displayed

Comment: @PaulVincentTansingco - so obviously your data is `Null` and you cannot add it.

Comment: so any suggestions im on the edge here :(

Comment: Write `If not IsNull (rs.Fields(0)) then`

Comment: Can you try the same code on a closed workbook? I've had problems before when trying to query sheets in the ActiveWorkbook.

Comment: @jivko I dont think it can eh?, because pertaining to the activeworkbook it will find the active workbook